# Convert svg to webp

Tags: android, image, android-studio, svg, webp

How can I convert an `svg` file to `webp` using Android Studio?
I don't see any convert to webp option when right clicking on the xml file and when I tried an online converter it produced 1 webp file while I was expecting a file for each definition folder `drawable-*dpi`
Also I don't see how I could import the `webp` in the project if I converted it from another tool.

Answer (score 2):

SVG is a vector graphic where WebP is a raster graphic.  These graphic types are not compatible.  You first need to convert the SVG to some sort of raster graphic.  You can do this by simply taking a screen shot of the image.  Then convert the screenshot from what ever raster format (usually PNG) to WebP.

Comment: I see some online tools to covert svg to png but they produce only 1 file. How can I produce a png per definition folder?

Comment: This tool looks like it will do multiple files: https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-webp

Comment: It produces 1 file

Comment: by the way that site converts from svg to webp (1 file only). Is there a way to convert from svg to png (multiple resolution files)?